# Registering Windows context menu handler provided by Microsoft's All-In-One framework (CppShellExtContextMenuHandler project)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, contextmenu, windows-shell

I've been using the CppShellExtContextMenuHandler sample project from Microsoft's All-In-One framework to add a custom menu item + icon to windows's context menu.

However, it seems that I can't register the DLL provided by this sample on other computers than mine. The DLL, compiled on a Windows 7 x86 machine from unmodified code, doesn't run on:

- Another Windows 7 x86
- A fresh Windows XP SP3 x86 install on VirtualBox

I get:

> LoadLibrary(CppShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll) Failed to find
>   specified procedure

(translated) on the XP machine

> The module "CppShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll"
>   failed to load.
>
> Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
>
> The specified module could not be found

on the other Windows 7 machine

I use `Regsvr32 CppShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll` in the commandline to register the DLL.

Did anyone encounter this problem? Did I miss something (dependencies/project config)?
I'm not sure how to debug this one.

Thank you for your help!

PS1: Code is available here: http://1code.codeplex.com/releases/view/71395, under ./Visual Studio 2010/CppShellExtContextMenuHandler in the package.

PS2: Compiled version of the sample is here: https://fgt.bo/GmQ

Comment: Aah. Found the solution! I had to redistribute the msvcr100.dll VC++ Runtime DLL along with my CppShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll to make it work. I'll post a more detailed answer as soon as stack overflows enables me to do it (ie: in 5 hours, apparently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer, thanks to [Choosing a Deployment Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316.aspx) on MSDN.

To make the DLL file compiled from the CppShellExtContextMenuHandler sample work on non-dev computers, you need to accompany it with the VC++ Runtime DLLs it depends on.

I used the [wonderful tool](http://dependencywalker.com/) on a client's (non-dev) machine to get the name of the DLLs my context menu handler depended on (the tool indicates which of them are missing on the arget computer!).

It turned out I had to redistribute the msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll files from [Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Redist] along with the CppShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll file to make it work.

To make the handler work on Windows XP, I also had to replace the two occurences of

> hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(RegDeleteTree(...

by:

> hr = SHDeleteKey(...

...in the Reg.cpp file. In fact, according to [C++ Windows Shell context menu handler Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppShellExtContextMenuHandl-410a709a/sourcecode?fileId=21956&pathId=1499387496), the RegDeleteTree function isn't available on XP.
The SHDeleteKey is equivalent and can be found in Shlwapi.h, on all versions of windows I tested.

Thank you for your time reading and trying to solve this!